# Why does my Ruby script running on Raspberry Pi die?

Tags: ruby, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi (256MB version) to monitor outside temperature and detect movement in a shed. There are three things at work to accomplish this:

1. a ruby script which runs every minute and records the temperature each minute. Depending on the current time, it will also upload the temperature to 3 different web services (at 5, 10 ,15 mins past the hour etc) and tweets it (on the hour)
2. a long running Ruby script which runs at reboot and watches for files being created by the motion detection software, then uploads them to Dropbox
3. [Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) - the motion detection software

The scripts are launched in the root users crontab like so:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby /usr/share/shed_watcher/lib/shed_watcher.rb >> /tmp/cron_shed_watcher.log 2>&1
@reboot /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby /usr/share/shed_watcher/lib/file_monitor.rb >> /tmp/file_monitor.log 2>&1
```

What I have noticed recently is that within seconds of motion being detected the Pi becomes unresponsive and after reboot the cron_shed_watcher.log log file contains entries such as:

```
    2014-04-03T19:55:17:342 - RAM USAGE: 28460K: stored temperatures are ["8.625\n", "8.625\n", "8.625\n", "8.625\n", "8.625\n"]

2014-04-03T19:55:17:332 - RAM USAGE: 28460K: temperature is 8.625

2014-04-03T19:55:17:376 - RAM USAGE: 28460K: average temperature is: 8.625



2014-04-03T20:00:28:812 - RAM USAGE: 28456K: temperature is 8.562

2014-04-03T20:00:28:843 - RAM USAGE: 28460K: average temperature is: 8.587

2014-04-03T20:00:28:822 - RAM USAGE: 28460K: stored temperatures are ["8.562\n", "8.625\n", "8.625\n", "8.562\n", "8.562\n"]



2014-04-03T20:05:17:312 - RAM USAGE: 28460K: temperature is 8.5

2014-04-03T20:05:17:322 - RAM USAGE: 28460K: stored temperatures are ["8.562\n", "8.562\n", "8.562\n", "8.5\n", "8.5\n"]

2014-04-03T20:05:17:346 - RAM USAGE: 28460K: average temperature is: 8.537


Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
Killed
```

To recover from whatever is happening during the `Killed` phase, I need to reboot. I have no clue as to where the `Killed` log entries are coming from. My suspicion was that there was an out of memory problem, hence the RAM info in the log entries, but this seems to remain steady. I also suspected the file monitor Ruby script was a more likely culprit for any memory problem so I made each script write to a different log file. However, the `Killed` log entries appear in the temperature script (`cron_shed_watcher.log`) and not the file monitor log file.

Here is the shed_watcher.rb Ruby script (edited to remove unnecessary detail):

```
        now = DateTime.now
        shed_temp = Temperature.new
        temp = shed_temp.celcius

            #tweet & email###
            if now.min == 0
                Tweeter.tweet TimeUtils.get_now_as_string(TimeUtils.get_local_time(now)), ave_temp.round(1)

                if now.hour == 6
                    GMailer.email_graph :daily, now
                    if now.sunday?
                        GMailer.email_graph :weekly, now
                    end
                    if now.day == 1
                        GMailer.email_graph :monthly, now
                    end
                    if now.month == 1 && now.day == 1
                        GMailer.email_graph :yearly, now
                    end
                end
            end

            #Xively###
#create json for Xively web service 

            #Met Office############## --- 
#create url for Met Officeweb service 

            #open sen.se###
#create json for Open Sense web service

            #post to web###
            begin
                Exception => e
                Logger.log "RestClient raised exception:"
                Logger.log e.message
            end
        end
```

And here is the Temperature class which gets the temperature from hardware:

```
class Temperature
    attr_reader :celcius, :fahrenheit
    def initialize
        @celcius = -999
        @fahrenheit = -999

        `modprobe w1-gpio`
        `modprobe w1-therm`

        base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
        device_folder = Dir.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
        @device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

        read_temp
    end
end

def read_temp_raw
    File.open(@device_file, 'r') do |f|
        lines = f.readlines()
    end
end

def read_temp
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    temp_c = 0
    temp_f = 0
    while !lines[0].strip().end_with? 'YES'
        sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw
    end
    equals_pos = lines[1].rindex('=')
    if equals_pos != -1
        line=lines[1].strip
        line=line[line.index('=') + 1, line.length - line.index('=') + 1]
        temp_c = line.to_f / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        @celcius = temp_c
        @fahrenheit = temp_f
    end
end
```

As you can see, this class makes some Linux system calls: `modprobe w1-gpio` and `modprobe w1-therm`

The file_monitor.rb script (run at reboot) looks like this:

```
class FileWatcher

    def initialize
        client = DropboxClient.new(ACCESS_TOKEN)
        begin
            FSSM.monitor('/tmp/motion/', '**/*', :directories => true) do
                update do |base, relative|
                end
                delete do |base, relative|
                end
                create do |base, relative|
                    Logger.log "Create called with #{relative}"
                    now = DateTime.now

                    Logger.log "Uploading #{File.absolute_path(relative, base)} to dropbox then deleting"
                    begin
                        client.put_file(relative, File.new(File.absolute_path(relative, base)))
                        File.delete(File.absolute_path(relative, base))
                    rescue Exception => e
                        Logger.log "Dropbox upload raised exception:"
                        Logger.log e.message
                        File.open('files_to_process.txt', 'a') do | file |
                            file.puts File.absolute_path(relative, base)
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        rescue Exception => e
            Logger.log "FileWatcher raised exception:"
            Logger.log e.message
        end
    end
end

fw = FileWatcher.new
```

If motion is detected, around one jpg file per second is created in `/tmp/motion/`.

How can I track down the reason for these log entries and the device dying?